# Web deploy issue with sitecore media files

Tags: sitecore, microsoft-web-deploy, webdeploy-3.5

I am using File system for media and trying to get Web Deploy to work between CM and CD but running into issue when I try to publish media item.

My WebDeploy.config looks like this:

```
<targetDatabase>web</targetDatabase>
<targetServer>cd-site</targetServer>
<userName>Administrator</userName>
<password>pwd</password>
<localRoot>C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CM\Website</localRoot>
<remoteRoot>C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CD\Website</remoteRoot>
<items hint="list:AddPath">
  <media>App_Data/MediaFiles</media>
</items>
```

I cant seem to get pass this error in sitecore after publish, any ideas?:

```
5652 02:01:11 INFO  Job started: Publish to 'web' 
ManagedPoolThread #13 02:01:11 INFO  MSDEPLOY: Performing synchronization for App_Data/MediaFiles
ManagedPoolThread #13 02:01:11 ERROR MSDEPLOY: Failed to synchronize folder App_Data/MediaFiles. Please verify that the folder exists and is accessible.
Exception: Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgentUnavailableException: Remote agent (URL http://cd-site/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE) could not be contacted.  Make sure the remote agent service is installed and started on the target computer. ---> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: An unsupported response was received. The response header 'MSDeploy.Response' was '' but 'v1' was expected. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.GetHttpResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.GetHttpResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.CreateStatusThread(DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.RemoteDestSync(DeploymentObject sourceObject, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
at Sitecore.Publishing.WebDeploy.DeploymentTaskRunner.Execute()
```

Comment: Have you seen this blog post? https://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/is-your-publishing-stuck-and-and-log-file-shows-due-to-webdeploy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by installing Web Deploy from WebPI. For some reason when I only installed Web Deploy 3.6 independently the services were not registered properly. After installing via WebPI the publishing job instantly started working.